# How to delete a feature from attribute table in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: attribute-table, editing, arcgis-online

How to delete a feature from attribute table in ArcGIS Online?

Comment: You must have editing enabled.  Then you click on the feature and the pop-up appears, from there you will hit delete and it will then delete the entire record.

Comment: I already did but I don't get the pop-up.

Comment: Click on the layer you want a pop-up to appear in.  Then click enable pop-up, then configure your pop-up.  The delete will be at the bottom.

Comment: The pop-up in on but still when I select one of the features from attribute list i don't see anything. I can select features on the map and delete them but it would take me a while. That's why I thought if I could select a bunch of them from the attribute table it would make it easier.

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood,  you cannot delete from the attribute table, only edit.  To delete you would have to select the point on the map and delete it from the pop-up.  I dont think there is a way to highlight multiple records and delete them all at once.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you cannot delete features from a table, you can only edit attributes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy way to delete multiple records from an ArcGIS Online table or layer, whether or not the record has geometry.

Just go to the service URL (bottom right of the item details page), scroll to the bottom, and click applyEdits. Then enter a comma-separated list of objectIDs you wish to delete and click Apply Edits.

Answer (score 0):

This is really annoying if you have a non spatial layer. The below python script will delete a feature with the objectid 1 from a feature layer.

```
from urllib import urlencode
import urllib2
formData=urlencode({
            u"f":u"json",
            u"deletes":1
    })
editUserUrl = "<some arcgisonline rest/services url>/FeatureServer/0/applyEdits"
deleterecord = urllib2.urlopen(url=editUserUrl,data=formData)
```